# Redirect a domain to a path but exclude some urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains.

Let's just call them

`example.com` and `example.de.`

Now, when someone types `example.com` in the address he comes to my site `example.com`. However, if the user types in `example.de` he will be redirected to `example.com/de`. The same goes for paths:

`example.de/a` => `example.com/de/a`

What I want to achieve now, is, that "specific" urls shouldn't be redirected.

So, while

`example.de/a` should still redirect to `example.com/de/a/`
`example.de/b/` should stay `example.de/b/`

So, currently my .htaccess, part of it, looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{http_host} example\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now, I want to exclude specific URLs so what I did so far were the following things

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} example\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/b
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem is, that `.de/b` still redirects to `.com/de/b`

Another part, which might be interesting for you is that in the last line of the `.htaccess` I redirect anything that doesn't end with `.com` to `.com`.

```
### SUBDOMAIN REDIRECT *.DOMAIN.TLD -> www.DOMAIN.TLD
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So, anyone any idea, what could solve this problem?

#### To respond to anubhava answer

I've changed my .htaccess now to this

```
### SUBDOMAIN REDIRECT *.DOMAIN.TLD -> www.DOMAIN.TLD
RewriteCond %{http_host} example\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/b
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/de/$1 [L,R=301]

### SUBDOMAIN REDIRECT *.DOMAIN.TLD -> www.DOMAIN.TLD
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/b
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But the problem is still there. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use `THE_REQUEST` variable in your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} example\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/b
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Hi, I changed it, but now it redirects me from

`example.de/b` to `example.com/b/`. Does this connect to my last 2 lines where I redirect any non-.com ending to .com-ending? If yes, I also added the rule there. I'll edit my OP for your answer

Comment: Yes right, you need `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/b` condition in last rule also.

Comment: It is there, but I'm still getting redirected, sadly.

Comment: Test it in a new browser and also post your complete .htaccess for more investigation.

Comment: Ah! Testing in new browser solved the problem. Seems like it was still in cache, thank you very much! Need to wait 2 minutes before I can accept, though

Comment: Well, another problem exists now. On the site, that applies to the rule, the css cannot be loaded. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Could this be, because the path to the .css is relative and not absoloute? `/css/base.css`

Comment: Yes that is right, not using absolute is indeed the problem. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
OR you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Hi. All my paths start with `/`. But I think the problem is, that, the .htaccess now tries to open all styles like this

`example.com/de/css/base.css` and that file doesn't exists. I'll try it by just using the absoloute pathes and will report

Comment: You can always make your condition to: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(b|css/|js/)` to ignore these css/js files to be rewritten/redirected.